# Python Pandas freezing why?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, syntax-error

(I'm not very good in English but I will do my best)
Version of pandas = 1.3.4, python = 3.10.6 in all my env conda. And out of conda : python = 3.9.12 and pandas = 1.3.4
I'm working with Pandas since multiple years.
I often do this syntax in my script :

```
df[df['Column']=='Value']
```

But now it doesn't work at all and freeze all my scripts with no error at all in prompt.
I'm working on ubuntu 22 with Miniconda and i have multiple env.

The code i'm struggling with :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("data/corpus.csv") 
print(df.shape)
df = df[df['Title']=='Yes']
print(df['Title'])
```

And this part of code work

```
var = df['Title']=='Yes'
```

But this wont:

```
df = df[var]
```

The print of df.shape is working but final print never show up, and prompt never print the end of interpreting the code.

I did try on different envs but that did not change the result of freezing my script.
The csv file is basic, nothing special, i did try with a new one created for testing but no change.
I did try in jupyter-notebook and in the terminal python prompt, no change.

I don't know what to do next, if you need more informations, i'm here to give it to you quickly.

Best regards,

Comment: How big is your .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from python=3.10.6. I downgrade to 3.8.16 and it's working well.
Thanks a lot Rainflow for your help.